# Mask inherited public property

Tags: c#

I want to create a new class inherited from button (Winform). I want to "remove" the `Text` property and replace it by my own property :

```
public partial class ButtonLetter : Button
{
    public char Letter
    {
        get
        {
            char _letter;
            if (char.TryParse(Text, out _letter))
                return _letter;
            else
                return ' ';
        }
        set
        {
            Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    private new string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

}

But when I use this control, the designer creates this code :

```
this.buttonLetter1.Letter = 'A';
this.buttonLetter1.Name = "buttonLetter1";
this.buttonLetter1.Text = "buttonLetter1";
```

And it works, the `Text` property is modify and my button contains "buttonLetter1" instead of "A".

Is there a way to mask the `Text` property to prevent its access ? (In this case the property should not be visible in designer => it is considered as private)

Comment: @Sinatr I've try this way but this solution don't prevent to use `Text` property. I want that my `ButtonLetter` acts like property `Text` is private

Comment: There is no way of preventing access, even with the `new` keyword. In the mentioned example, simply casting the object to a `Button` allows someone to access the original `Text` property: `((Button)this.ButtonLetter1).Text = "Foobar";`

Comment: Why do you want to make it `private`? Can you explain what you want to archive and why `public` text is a problem?

Comment: @Sinatr Cause my button must only display a char. I want to force user to use my property `Letter` typed as char instead of `Text` typed as string